# How FrameLayout works in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

[image]

I am trying achieve the above design but using Frame Layout the blue image is not showing above the white background. Where is the mistake, please help?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adapter_flParent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:translationZ="1dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:text="Regional Snooker" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_org"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adapter_Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:text="Concered Authority"/>

</RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/adapter_blue" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:text="PASSED"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am trying to get the blue image but unable to get this blue image above white background using framelayout and also have to add the love image above blue image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adapter_flParent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/ten_dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_corner_radius_background"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/adapter_Title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:text="Regional Snooker"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/adapter_org"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:text="Concered Authority"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adapter_data"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/test_blue_bg"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:text="PASSED"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_round_favorite_unfilled" />

    </FrameLayout>
```